# Cannot connect to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB -> Login failed for user 'User-PC\User'

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, localdb

I am getting an error, While I am trying to connect (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB through SQL Server management studio. I also tried to login with default database as master the error is same.

[image]
Here is the Server details.
[image]

Comment: Also remember to not escape one backslash like `appsettings.json` `ConnectionStrings` `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb`. Correct is `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**Warning: this will delete all your databases located in MSSQLLocalDB. Proceed with caution.**

The following command through sqllocaldb utility works for me.

```
sqllocaldb stop mssqllocaldb
sqllocaldb delete mssqllocaldb
sqllocaldb start "MSSQLLocalDB"
```

[image]

After that I restarted the sql server management studio, and it is successfully established connection through `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: Restarting VisualStudio is also required if this is the DB tool you're using (as you mentionned for SSMS).

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed worked for me too ! Thanks! .. Strange error .

Comment: Warning ! this will delete all your databases located in MSSQLLocalDB if you use the delete command

Comment: Trying what you posted above only worked for me after I tricked the MSSQLLocalDb instance into erroring out. This was because I was getting an error on Windows API call LogSqlDiagRec when trying to run sqllocaldb stop mssqllocaldb. I updated the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances\ParentInstance value from MSSQL13E.LOCALDB to MSSQL13.1E.LOCALDB and back to MSSQL13E.LOCALDB again. This invalid value 13.1 forced MSSQLLocalDB into a Stopped State. This allowed me to delete and start the mssqllocaldb again. Once I did that I was able to login to localdb in SSMS.

Comment: I had a problem like this, but where the "Instance pipe name" was empty, I tried googling the problem but ended up trying this solution, and it also worked for me.

Comment: I'm just dealing with a Visual Studio issue where my unit tests throw these `login failed for user` errors (I don't even have SQL Enterprise Studio installed). Even though I drop the connections from my `Server Explorer` - nothing works until I restart Visual Studio

Comment: You Sir, are a genius!! I was struggling my butt off trying to figure out why a winforms app did not work on a brand new pc of a client when he resinstalled, but it works on every other pc we install it on. After trying everything, this was the only solution that worked!

Comment: I'm getting an error when starting the instance (third command): Cannot create an automatic instance. How do I get past this please?

Comment: Thank you. I have been uninstalling and installing SQL server and visual studio for more then 3 times taking me almost 2 day. But, your solution helped me in less than 1 min.

Comment: This just worked like magic. Thanks a lot. I have spent a whole day trying to figure out this error.

Comment: FYI, you can use `sqllocaldb stop mssqllocaldb -k` to force stop a misbehaving instance.

Comment: OMG I deleted all my localdb databases.
You should have put a BIG warning!

Comment: This solution worked with out problems, and I connected instantly

Answer (score 3):

For this particular error, what gave me access to my MDF in VS2019 was:

1. In Solution Explorer, right click your MDF file
2. Detach

That was it and I now have access.  I was expecting to detach and attach, but that wasn't needed.

I also could not get to my (localdb) in SSMS either, so what helped me there was a solution by Leniel Maccaferri. Here is the link to his site, along with the excerpt that helped me:

https://www.leniel.net/2014/02/localdb-sqlserver-2012-cannot-open-database-requested-by-login-the-login-failed-error-4060.html

[image]

So guess what: the solution is ridiculously easy once you know what to do of course…

Click that Options >> button in Figure 1. Now select the Connection Properties tab.

SSMS Connect to Server | Connection Properties | Connect to database optionFigure 2 - SSMS Connect to Server | Connection Properties | Connect to database option

I had to type master in Connect to database field since I did not have it in the list of available databases.

Now click connect and you’re done.

Comment: Worth mentioning to check "Additional Connection Parameters" too in case you're an idiot like me and had a database name being set in there too!

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

1. using Windows + R
2. then type services.mcs
3. then find sql server which was off.
4. I've run it using right-click. Then connection was back